# Get values from ajax to insert in models codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How do I get values of input fields via AJAX from controllers to appear in (CodeIgniter) Models?

I have input fields from AJAX call. Here is my code so far:

**Controllers**

```
$name = $_POST('name');
$bod = $_POST('bod');
$address = $_POST('address');
$result = $this->main->insert_db($time);
```

**Models**

```
public function $insert_db($time){
    $data = array('time'=>$time,
        'name'=>????, 
        'bod'=>????,
        'address'=>?????
    );
    $this->db->insert('db',$data);  
}
```

Comment: explore your question.

Comment: assign the id to input field then get value through the jquery and pass to controller.

Answer (score 0):

1) pass those data as parameter to your insert_db($time, $name, $bod, $address) method.

2) access them directly using 
    $this->input->post('name'); 
    $this->input->post('bod'); 
    $this->input->post('address'); 
in your model.

// don't use post array directly 
// use $this->input->post();

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot pass the data as parameters, coz it'll have a lot of job on my part, that's why I am asking if there's any possible way to do it.

Comment: How do i access them? using $this->input->post()? when at first place these fields are from AJAX and you can only access it via $_POST??

Comment: understand that Ajax or page reload it does not make any difference. $this->input->post(field_name); will give u data...

Comment: My fields are not belong into same project application, it was outside of my application, example. data will be inserted here. http.x1.com the fields to be inserted was here http.x2.com. will that work?

Comment: r u trying to ask "how to post values via ajax to backend ?"